# In Laravel Observer Not tracking eloquent event like created,updated,deleted

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have on model User in that i am insert record bulk but observer not working in these scenario it will not detect it's create,update,delete event but if i use create it's work perfectly any other work around also accepted. If any one help in these scenario it will be highly appreciate.

Model App/User.php

```
$raw_data = [
    [
        'name' => 'stackoverflow'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'stackoverflow1'
    ],

];

User::insert($raw_data);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because *saved* and *updated* events aren't fired (when bulk updates). Please see the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models):

> When issuing a mass update via Eloquent, the saved and updated model events will not be fired for the updated models. This is because the models are never actually retrieved when issuing a mass update.

Nothing you can do. Unless you use a loop to make the creates.

Comment: Thanks for answering me but is there any work around?

Comment: The only workaround I see is to use a loop (over your *raw_data* variable) and create a new model instance for each insert.

Answer (score 1):

As [@salah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54007145/7117697) said, you can't trigger events when doing mass-operations. As a workaround you could try:

```php
$raw_data = [
    [
        'name' => 'Jane Doe'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'John Doe'
    ],
];

collect($raw_data)
    ->each(function ($data) {
        User::create($data);
    });
```